# Adding Formula to Cell from Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a macro button in worksheet 2 and want it to put a formula into a column of worksheet 1. 
For example I can do a simple sum formula  such  as:

```
Sheets("worksheet1").Range("I:I") = "=SUM(M:M)"
```

This works but when I try and do it with the actual more complicated formula I want it will not work.
Why is this?

```
Sheets("worksheet1").Range("I:I") = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*567*",B:B)),"INSTOCK","")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a double quote like you did makes VBA think you ended your string after just writing `"=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("`. In fact, this code will error out. You'll need to double-up your quotes. A great way to understand what you are writing would be to use `Debug.Print` first:

```
Debug.Print "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*567*"",B:B)),""INSTOCK"","""")"
```

So this will work:

```
Sheets("worksheet1").Range("I:I") = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*567*"",B:B)),""INSTOCK"","""")"
```

**Note:** since you are using whole column references, this is going to be heavy on your calculation!

Comment: Thanks, How would I make it only go down as far as the last populated cell in Column A? so i dont have to select the whole Column.

Comment: Create a dynamic range object =). Find your last used row. There are many posts around showing you how.