# Adding an OR Function to IF Statement

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, search, excel-formula

How do I make this formula search for *567* or *676* or *342* instead of just *567* which it is at the moment.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*567*"",B:B)),""Traction"","""")
```

Comment: Is this a follow-up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59785221/9758194) question? If so, it could be wise to state that you want this done through VBA.

Answer (score 2):

You can evaluate more than one clause using `OR`:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("567",B:B)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("676",B:B)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("342",B:B))),"Traction","")
```

Using `OR` allows you to specify two or more clauses which will return `true` if *any* of them are true:

```
=IF(OR(clause_1, clause_2, clause_3, etc.), true, false)
```

The `OR` function is documented [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0).

Comment: This is the long way round, but negates the need to transpose (and would avoid possible confusion =)). Upvoted

Answer (score 2):

As a formula, you could simple try:

```
=IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({567;676;342},B:B)))>0,"Traction","")
```

We have to use the semi-colon to evaluate each element in the array against all values in the `B:B` range.

**Note1:** This is a `CSE` formula and needs to be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shifter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Note2:** If this is indeed a follow-up on your previous question, you'll need to enter it like so:

```
<YourInputRange>.FormulaArray = "=IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""567"";""676"";""342""},B:B)))>0,""Traction"","""")"
```

Or, depending on your `Locale`:

```
<YourInputRange>.FormulaArray = "=IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""567"",""676"",""342""},B:B)))>0,""Traction"","""")"
```

**Note3:** As per my previous answer, you are comparing whole columns in an array formula. Be aware that this will impact your performance. I would advise your next step is to really get dynamic `Range` objects.

---

***<sub>EDIT</sub>***

A small explaination on why we either need to `TRANSPOSE` the values in column `B:B` OR those in our array. Let's imagine some sample data In `B1:B3`:

[image]

Let's focus on our formula; `IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({567,676,342},B1:B3)))>0,"Traction","")`. Notice how we currently compare two vertical ranges. So Basically what we are asking the formula could look like:

[image]>[image]

The answer is triple-negative! So in this case the result will be `""`.

Now let's compare a vertical array against a horizontal one, our formula now looks like: `=IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({567;676;342},B1:B3)))>0,"Traction","")`,  to visualize this you could think of a matrix:

[image]

There is one positive match in our matrix! Now because this is comparing two arrays, we need to `CSE` the formula. And this is why we rather have a specified range, e.g. `B1:B3`, instead of a full column reference.

Comment: I have been thinking for a long time about forcing SEARCH to search multiple values at once. It turns out that all the salt is in commas and semicolons. Those who need to separate arguments by semicolon in formulas must do the opposite - value array must be separated by commas.

Comment: @basic, very true. In my personal case these commas will be transformed into backslashes. The whole point is to create a matrix where a horizontal array is compared to a vertical one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - that explains why COUNT works when ISNUMBER doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You don't need the wildcards with SEARCH.

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"567","676","342"},B:B)),"Traction","")
```

Comment: That has not worked. i have tried =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""567"", ""676"", ""342""},B:B)),""Traction"","""") aswell which i think may be closer but still doesnt work

Comment: because "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""567""},B:B)),""Traction"","""")" worked but i just need to add in 676 and 342

Comment: Apologies, hadn't spotted that. I've amended above and it works for me (without the doubled quotes).

Comment: I've clicked to upvote but to realize later you are not comparing all values in your array against all values in column `B:B` =) > `=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"567","676","342"},TRANSPOSE(B1:B3))),"Traction","")` will do so. Or actually: `=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"567";"676";"342"},B:B)),"Traction","")`

Comment: sorry i have double quotations because I am typing this in as a macro   Sheets("Data").Range("I:I") = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""567""},B:B)),""Traction"","""")"

Comment: @JvdV - bah I should never go near formulae, I thought I had used this one in the past and it had worked. The whole column reference confused me. I'll probably delete this answer once OP has fed back.

Comment: @SJR, your formula is fine as soon you change the commas to semi-colon. My vote is still there (even think your formula > mine). So don't doubt!

Comment: @JvdV - thanks. The change to COUNT works for me (with commas). But I don't understand why and neither do I understand the comma/semi-colon issue and I don't like to post things I don't really understand!

Comment: @SJR, I've tried to visualize the difference in my post. Hopefully that takes away your doubt.